# How do I share Google photos?

Tags: media, 9

I would like to have all shared albums of a certain google account automatically into a Drupal website.
I was able to establish a connection with 'Google_photos_api' and show all shared albums on site with code below.

```
<?php
$GooglePhotosService = \Drupal::service('google_photos_api.client');
try {
  $optParams=array("pageSize" => 50);
  $SharedAlbumlijst = $GooglePhotosService->googleServicePhotosLibrary->sharedAlbums->listSharedAlbums($optParams);  
  ksm($SharedAlbumlijst);  
  echo '<div id="GooglePhotos" class="grid views-view-grid">';
  echo '<div class="row">';  
  foreach ($SharedAlbumlijst as $album) {
    echo '<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">';    
    // Get some properties of an album
    $albumId = $album->getId();
    $title = $album->getTitle();
    $productUrl = $album->getProductUrl();
    $coverPhotoBaseUrl = $album->getCoverPhotoBaseUrl() . '=w200-h200-c';
    echo '<h5>' . $title . '</h5>';
    echo '<a href="' . $coverPhotoBaseUrl . '" id="' . $albumId . '">';
    echo '<img src="' . $coverPhotoBaseUrl . '" alt="' . $title . '">';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  ksm($e);
}
```

The problem I cannot figure out is to list all media-items of a given album. Code below is not functioning. I don't know how to pass the albumID into this??

```
<?php
$GooglePhotosService = \Drupal::service('google_photos_api.client');

try {
  $albumId = 'ANfpKL0unQw8nWACRpVCPj0JxmZ5JHkX_xCecI-VPFxKrFScPPfpE8HakFWvKG3KFVXNnNyigXB0';
  $optParams = ['albumId' => $albumId];
  $mediaItems = $GooglePhotosService->googleServicePhotosLibrary->mediaItems->search($optParams);

  ksm($MediaItems);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
  ksm($e);
}
```

Any help would be great!!
Thanks in advance!!

```
Error code:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Resource_MediaItems::search() must be an instance of Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_SearchMediaItemsRequest, array given, called in C:\Xampp2\htdocs\Demertr\modules\contrib\php\php.module(81) : eval()'d code on line 7 in Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Resource_MediaItems->search() (line 79 of vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\PhotosLibrary\Resource\MediaItems.php).
```

`MediaItems.php`

```
class Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Resource_MediaItems extends Google_Service_Resource {

public function search(Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_SearchMediaItemsRequest $postBody, $optParams = []) {
    $params = ['postBody' => $postBody];
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('search', [$params], 'Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_SearchMediaItemsResponse');
  }
}
```

```
SearchMediaItemsRequest.php

class Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_SearchMediaItemsRequest extends Google_Model {
  public $albumId;
  protected $filtersType = 'Google_Service_PhotosLibrary_Filters';
  protected $filtersDataType = '';
  public $pageSize;
  public $pageToken;
...
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers! This question might get more attention and better answers on https://stackoverflow.com/, as it's not directly related to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

No idea really, but looking at the error message and the docs at https://google.github.io/php-photoslibrary/v1.1.0/classes/Google.Photos.Library.V1.SearchMediaItemsRequest.html (if that is the right version), I would say that you need to create an instance of `SearchMediaItemsRequest`, set the album id on that object and then pass that into the `search` method. So maybe something like this based on your code:

```
$media_request = new SearchMediaItemsRequest();
$media_request->setAlbumId($albumId);
$mediaItems = $GooglePhotosService->googleServicePhotosLibrary->mediaItems->search($media_request);
```

Comment: Dear Berliner,
Thanks for your reaction, but I still cannot figure this out. I tried your suggestion, but then I'm getting another error:
`Error: Class 'SearchMediaItemsRequest' not found in eval() (line 11 of modules\contrib\php\php.module(81) : eval()'d code).`

Comment: Don't do this kind of stuff with the help of the PHP module. Like ever! Really, don't! It's bad!
Take the time instead to learn how Drupal works, then create a custom module and do it there. There are plenty of tutorials that will help you do this properly.

Comment: I run this code in my own module, only for testing I use the php module. But thanks anyway.